# Adobe DTM s.abort

Tags: adobe-analytics

I am trying to setup a rule in DTM to block the main analytics call going off.

Current set up 
using direct call rules to fire the analytics _satelite.track() becuase the site is using Ajax which means the page does not fully refresh.
When I manually refresh the page I get two calls going off one is from the direct call rule and the other is from the main sitecatalyst libraries

What do I want to do?
stop the main sitecat library from sending the analytics ONLY on pages where the following object is set with the value of "category"
digitalData.page.pageInfo.pageName = "category"

Any thoughts ?

Comment: is that direct call rule an s.tl(); call?

Answer (score 1):

To suppress the beacon that is inherently set on pageLoad when the analytics tool loads, you can just run "return false" in the Analytics Tool custom code block. 
http://www.digitaldatatactics.com/examples/DCRsuppress.html describes exactly that scenario.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to suppress the Adobe Analytics call based on certain logic, such as a certain page load rule firing, you can put `s.abort = true` in the custom code section of the Adobe Analytics tool in that rule.

Answer (score -4):

According to the official DTM forums, the return false is the correct method.

https://forums.adobe.com/message/9548019#9548019